# Upload Image through jquery Ajax into Model Data into Controller MVC/Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

View has data which is being passed to a controller through Ajax/jquery. It is not a form. Ajax call is made on Click function

Razor View

```
<div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddAUser.UserAgeMonths, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddAUser.UserAgeMonths, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "UserAgeMonths", @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
       <input type="file" name="AddAUser.UserImageFile" class="form-control-file" id = "UserProfileImage" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Model

```
[Column("intAgeMonths")]
[DisplayName("User's Age in Months")]
public Int16 UserAgeMonths { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
[DisplayName("Upload your profile picture")]
public HttpPostedFileBase UserImageFile { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult AddUser([FromBody]Customer user)
{
}
```

Ajax Jquery Call

```
  $('#AddButton').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();       
        var UserMonthsParam = $('#UserAgeMonths').val();
        var userParam = $('#LoggedInUser').val();
        var UserImageParam = $('#UserProfileImage').get(0).files;
        var button = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            //Url should contain the method you want to run
            url: "/api/customer/AddUser",
            //Method will be one of the REST API verb
            method: "POST",
            //These are all the parameters to be passed to method for rest api
            data: {               
                AgeMonths: UserMonthsParam,
                UserImageFile : UserImageParam[0]
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("User has been added successfully");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error occured!!")
            }
        });

    });
```

But I get an error while passing the image data to the controller. It says Illegal Invocation. I am not sure how to pass Image data to the Model data in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to upload images and save them.

In the below example I use a drop zone in the view but you can use whatever you need and save the data in the same way as the example below.

```
View 

<div class="details-form-container">
    <h3>Upload Photos</h3>
    <div class="spacer_0"></div>
    <div class="dropzone dz-form">
        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
            <p class="txt">
                Drop files here or click to upload.<br />
                <span>Valid extensions: <b>jpg, gif, png</b> | Max filesize: <b>4MB</b></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer_1"></div>
</div>


<script>

    $(".dz-form").dropzone({
    url: "@Url.Action("upload")",                            
    queuecomplete: function (file, response) {
    showAlert('alert', 'success', 'Photos', 'Upload complete.');
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("edit/" + @Model.AgentID  + "/photos")';
    }, 1000);
    }

</script>


Controller

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            bool isValid = false;

            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                if (file == null)
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
                if (file.ContentLength > 4 * 1024 * 1024)
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
                if (!UploadImage.IsFileTypeValid(file))
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
                isValid = true;

                if (isValid)
                {
                    // code to save the photo                    
                }
            }

            if (isValid == false)
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Error" });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Success" });
            }
        }
```

Comment: requires dropzone.js?

Comment: @pcalkins yes, it does